# How to print one side of the diagonal of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, visual-c++, multidimensional-array

Lets suppose we have a 5 X 5 random array
1 2 3 7 `8`
4 7 3 `6` 5
2 9 `8` 4 2
2 `9` 5 4 7
`3` 7 1 9 8
Now I want to print the right side of the diagonal shown above, along with the elements in the diagonal, like
----------8
--------6 5
------8 4 2
---9 5 4 7
3 7 1 9 8
The code I've written is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;

int main(){
    int rows, columns;

    cout << "Enter rows: ";
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "Enter colums: ";
    cin >> columns;

    int **array = new int *[rows]; // generating a random array
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        array[i] = new int[columns];

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL)); // random values to array

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){        // loop for generating a random array
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
            array[i][j] = rand() % 10;    // range of randoms
            cout << array[i][j] << " "; 
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << "For finding Max: " << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){//loop for the elements on the left of
        for(int j = columns; j > i; j--){//diagonal including the diagonal
             cout << array[i][j] << " "; 
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "For finding Min: " << endl;

    for(int i = rows; i >= 0; i++){           //loop for the lower side of 
        for(int j = 0; j < i - columns; j++){ //the diagonal
            cout << array[i][j] << " "; 
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After running the code the shape I get is correct , but the elements do not correspond to the main array. I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `for (int j = columns ` -> `for (int j = columns -1`, otherwise you access the array out of bounds, but anyway this is not what you actually want

Comment: I want the bounds included

Comment: @Dr.lackedu `array[rows][columns]` is out of bounds. the lower right element of the array is `array[rows - 1][columns - 1]`, the upper left element is `array[0][0]`

Comment: Who deletes the allocated memory?

Comment: If you want to add different question, after it got answered, you can open new question r add (and not replace) your new one.

Answer (score 1):

Left side:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for(size_t j = 0; j < columns - i; j++) {
         cout << array[i][j] << " "; 
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Right side:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        if (j < columns - i - 1) cout << "- ";
        else cout << vec[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: @Dr.lackedu yes it does, please elaborate and tell us what makes you think this does not work

Comment: @Dr.lackedu you can delete all of your comments to this answer as they are obsolete now.

Comment: @ Jabberwocky, would you please tell me how to print the lower side of the diagonal

Comment: @Dr.lackedu That is a different question! Don't alter your question in a way that totaly changes the original question you had!

Comment: Sorry Korel, that message was for @Dr.lackedu, edited.

Comment: @KorelK , I have to print both sides of the diagonal . As long as @Jabberwocky sorted out how to print the left side. Now I only need to print the `right/lower` side of the diagonal.

Comment: @Dr.lackedu in my answer's edit you can see how to print also the right side.